# Dividing household keeping individuals with link together

Tags: netlogo

I am programming for the first time in netlogo, so I am have a bit of difficulty. I am trying to simulate an indigenous community focusing on decisions regard time allocation to different productive activities (farming and hunting). In the whole model there will be demographic processes (reproduction, mortality), changes in agriculture and hunting routines etc. Now I am trying to model the dynamic of marriage and household divisions, that works like this: when people get married the male moves to the female house and becomes parts of the household. When the households become too crowd, they divide the household in two. I managed to do the divisions and create a new household with half of the members (considering child and adults) but I don't know how to keep the individuals married together. Therefore what I want to know is: if I randomly select a married member to be part of the new household, how do I do for the spouse goes too?

My code, till now, is like this (I am only showing the parts somehow related to the question to save space).

```
Breed [individuals individual]
Breed [households household]
undirected-link-breed [marriages marriage]

individuals-own [
  id
  sex
  age
  household-id
  married?
  mate-id
  married-prob
]

households-own [
  household-members
  adult-members
  child-members
]

patches-own [
  class
]



to setup
  clear-all
  create-households hsdsinitial
  [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set shape "house"
    let number-individuals random-normal initial-mean-hsds-size 6
    hatch-individuals number-individuals
     [
      ifelse random-bernoulli 0.5                ;; flip a coin
      [ set sex "male" ]
      [ set sex "female"]

      set age  max
      (list 0 random-exponential 23)
      if age > 97 [die]

      set household-id myself

      set married? false

    ]; end of hatch-individuals


  ] 

  do-marry

ask households [
set household-members individuals with [household-id = myself]
    set adult-members household-members with [age >= 16]
    set child-members household-members with [age < 16]



  reset-ticks


end

to go

  tick
  if ticks >= years-to-simulate [stop]


 do-marry
 hshd-division


end



to do-marry


    ask individuals with [ sex = "male" and not married?]
  [
    set married-prob (-0.028 * ln age + 0.1097)
          ]

            ask individuals with [ sex = "female" and not married?]
  [
    set married-prob (-0.056 * ln age + 0.1998)
          ]

 let bachelors individuals with [ not married? and age >= 16 and age <= 50]
  ask bachelors with [ sex = "male" ] [
    let potential-mates bachelors with [sex = "female" and household-id != [ household-id ] of myself]
    if any? potential-mates [
      if (random-float 1 <= married-prob and random-float 1 <= [married-prob] of one-of potential-mates) [
        let mate one-of potential-mates
        create-marriage-with mate
        set household-id [ household-id ] of mate
        set married? true
        set mate-id mate
        ask mate [set married? true
        set mate-id myself
        ]


   let destination-patch [patch-here] of household-id
    move-to destination-patch


    ask mate [hatch-individuals 1
      [
        ifelse random-bernoulli 0.5
        [ set sex "male" ]
        [ set sex "female"]

        set age 0
        set household-id [household-id] of myself
        set married? false
          ]
  ]
]]]



end

 to hshd-division


  ask households
 [ if ( count household-members) > max-hsds-member
    [let my-childs n-of ( count child-members / 2 ) individuals with [household-id = myself]
      let my-adults n-of ( count adult-members / 2 ) individuals with [household-id = myself]
      let my-members (turtle-set my-childs my-adults)
    create-new-hshd-from
       my-members]
  ]


end

to create-new-hshd-from [my-members]

  hatch-households 1
  [
    set household-members my-members
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor

    ask my-members
    [set household-id myself
      let mate individuals with [mate-id = one-of individuals with [household-id = myself]]
      ask mate [set household-id [household-id] of myself]
    let destination-patch [patch-here] of household-id
    move-to destination-patch
  ]
  ]


end
```